# How to efficiently flatten a hierarchical state machine?

Tags: graphs, data-structures, finite-automata, software-verification

David Harel's StateCharts introduces hierarchical states and history mechanism, which are really powerful when modeling complex system behaviour. But when doing model based testing we need a "flattened state machine", that is an equivalent state machine without any hierarchy.

By googling around I found [this paper](https://www.itu.dk/%7Ewasowski/papers/p085-wasowski.ps.gz) by Wasowski, but its a little bit too hard to understand.

Is there any existing algorithm for hierarchical state machine flattening?